# Default Constructor - deferring initialisation of member variables

Tags: c++, object, constructor, default-constructor

I am looking to create a default constructor for my object in C++, which, when called, simply calls another constructor but with fixed values.

I have been looking at similar problems:
[Are default constructors called automatically for member variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993134/are-default-constructors-called-automatically-for-member-variables) and 
[Explicitly defaulted constructors and initialisation of member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646685/explicitly-defaulted-constructors-and-initialisation-of-member-variables)
Which indicate, that when a default constructor is called, the default constructors of the member variables, unless specified, are also called.

However, the issue I have is that the member variables (from the ARMmbed library) I am using, do not have default constructors - hence this is not working.

Is there a way to "delay" this issue, because, in the constructor called by the default constructor, all these member variables are allocated to and it all works out - is there a way of letting the compiler know this?

Thanks very much!

The header and implementation code I am using is below!

```
class Motor: public PwmOut
{
public:
    //Constructor of 2 pins, and initial enable value
    Motor(); //Default constructor
    Motor(PinName dutyPin, PinName enable_pin, bool enable);  
private:
    bool enable; //Boolean value of enable
    DigitalOut enablePin; //Digital out of enable value
};
```

Implementation:

```
/**
* Default constructor
**/
Motor::Motor() //I don't want to initialise member variables here
{
    this = Motor::Motor(p23,p24,true); //As they are initialised in this constructor anyway?
}
/**
* Constructor for Motor class. Takes 1 PwmOut pin for PwmOut base class and 1 pin for DigitalOut enable
**/
Motor::Motor(PinName dutyPin, PinName enable_pin, bool enable):
    PwmOut(dutyPin), enablePin(enable_pin)
{
    //Logic in here - don't really want to duplicate to default constructor
}
```

Comment: You can [delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961037/delegate-constructor-c) the default constructor to use a parameterized constructor.

Comment: why don't you just give default values to the second constructor and make default constructor private?

Comment: I appreciate I could have done that, but a) I dont really want to repeat the logic code in the other constructor and b) I want to know if theoretically, it can be done :)

Comment: @davidhood2 It's odd that your `Motor` class inherits from `PwmOut`. Shouldn't you be using composition rather than inheritance? What if takes multiple PWM output pins to drive your motor?

Comment: @Praetorian The way its set up physically (the PwmOut ouput goes to a motor chip) led me to think that the motor object IS a type of PwmOut rather than containing a PwmOut - and I just followed the is-a/has-a convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C++11's delegating constructors feature for this.

```
Motor::Motor()
: Motor(p23,p24,true)
{}
```

---

If your compiler does not support that then you'll have to initialize the data members in the mem-initializer list, and move the logic that you do not want repeated to another function.

```
Motor::Motor()
: PwmOut(p23), enablePin(p24), enable(true)
{
    Init();
}

Motor::Motor(PinName dutyPin, PinName enable_pin, bool enable):
    PwmOut(dutyPin), enablePin(enable_pin), enable(enable)
{
    Init();
}

Motor::Init()
{
  // Move the initialization logic in here
}
```

---

Another option, as [Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) mentions in the comments, is to introduce a base class that you can delegate construction to.

```
class MotorBase
{
public:
    MotorBase(PinName enable_pin, bool enable)
    : enable(enable), enablePin(enable_pin)
    {
       // initialization logic goes in here
    }
private:
    bool enable; //Boolean value of enable
    DigitalOut enablePin; //Digital out of enable value
};

class Motor : public PwmOut, MotorBase
{
public:
    Motor(); //Default constructor
    Motor(PinName dutyPin, PinName enable_pin, bool enable);
};

Motor::Motor()
: PwmOut(p23), MotorBase(p24, true)
{}

Motor::Motor(PinName dutyPin, PinName enable_pin, bool enable):
    PwmOut(dutyPin), MotorBase(enable_pin, enable)
{}
```

Comment: @davidhood2: In C++03 you can delegate to an artificial base class.

Comment: @davidhood2 You can either add an `Init()` (maybe `private`) member function or delegate to some base class as Alf suggests

Comment: @praetorian: the update introduced some bad advice about introducing redundancy and using an `init` function abomination to avoid even more redundancy. ouch.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, it's far from ideal but aside from the repeated mem-initializer list, it's not really as bad as the usual `init` function two phase initialization that's frowned upon because your class will still be fully initialized after a call to either constructor.